# What is the difference between tensorflow.keras.backend.round and tf.round?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

if i have some tensorflow function foo

```py
@tf.function
def foo(x):
    return tf.keras.backand.round(x)
```

and function bar

```py
@tf.function
def bar(x):
    return tf.round(x)
```

what is the difference between foo and bar?

i expect that sombody answer on my question

Answer (score 0):

As TensorFlow is open-source on GitGub, you can simply check the code there.

Currently (TensorFlow v2.12.0) all tf.keras.backand.round(x) does is to call tf.round(x). Therefore, the result of either will be the same.

Comment: You can look up the respective code here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.12.0/keras/backend.py#L3096-L3110, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.12.0/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L908-L934